# Retrieving indexed Ids from an indexed column in database is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, linq

I have to select all the rows from a database table containing a defined (long)sessionId where the sessionId row is indexed. But it is slow, and since the code to access it is really simple, I'm wondering where the problem is. Here is the code of the three layers:

```
var localPath = BusinessClient.Instance.Tracker.GetSpecifiedMilestonesInSessionObjects(milestonesInSession.SessionId).ToList();
```

---

```
public IQueryable<MilestonesInSession> GetSpecifiedMilestonesInSessionObjects(long sessionId)
{
    var query = from m in _milestonesInSessionRepository.GetAll()
                where m.SessionId == sessionId
                select m;

    return query;
}
```

---

```
public IQueryable<Model.Tracker.MilestonesInSession> GetAll()
{
    var query = from milestoneSession in _dataContext.Repository<Linq.TrackerMilestonesInSession>()
                select new Model.Tracker.MilestonesInSession
                           {
                               MilestoneId = milestoneSession.MilestoneId,
                               CreatedDate = milestoneSession.CreatedDate,
                               SessionId = milestoneSession.SessionId,
                               ProductId = milestoneSession.ProductId,
                               TrackerId = milestoneSession.TrackerId,
                               StatusId = milestoneSession.StatusId,
                               BankId = milestoneSession.BankId
                           };
    return query;
}
```

Here attached the screenshot of the performance using ANTS:

Presentation Layer 
[image]

Business Layer
[image]

Data Access Layer
[image]

Comment: Run SQL Server Profiler, intercept the query, run an explain / query plan on it. This can't be answered without knowing your database layout.

Comment: This is the query built:
{SELECT [t0].[SessionId], [t0].[MilestoneId], [t0].[CreatedDate], [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[TrackerId], [t0].[StatusId], [t0].[BankId]
FROM [dbo].[TrackerMilestonesInSessions] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[SessionId] = @p0
}

Comment: I can't do anything with that query, I don't have your database. **You** have to run that query in SSMS and show the execution plan, which will show any bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return all the rows, you will hardly fully use an index, unless the index has all the rows (whihc is not a good apporach)

Bear in mind that the index usage is also related with the columns you have on your select. If you have a table with ID and Name, with an index on name, and select * from it the index probably wont be used.

Run your query on SSMS with the "Include actual execution plan" option selected to see if the index is being used or not

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article for DB optimization, take a look through it.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

You need to find out whether the bottleneck is the code, or the actual query.  **Antz** will only tell you the result of the call in the code, but that code needs to speak to the DB etc.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is the actual query

```
SELECT [t0].[SessionId]
    , [t0].[MilestoneId]
    , [t0].[CreatedDate]
    , [t0].[ProductId]
    , [t0].[TrackerId]
    , [t0].[StatusId]
    , [t0].[BankId] 
FROM [dbo].[TrackerMilestonesInSessions] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[SessionId] = @p0
```

you're not only pulling out indexed sessionId, you're also pulling out non idexed columns (milestone, createddate, productid, trackerId, statusid, bankid). Looks like the actual table is so large that your row lookups become an actual performance issue.

Suggestions in this case:

- Run usual database housekeeping tasks: index rebuilds, statistics update
- Partitionining the table could be an option
- as a last not recommended solution you can add all those fields to the index, that will speed up the select, but will make inserts slow, and make your index bloated.

Without knowing more about application architecture and purpse it's all I can recommend.

Comment: This is shotgun debugging: _"I don't know what it is, so I'll just click here"_. There are plenty of tools out there that can tell you exactly **why** a certain query is slow. You are advising just to guess and to add an index to columns which aren't in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Name a few... "Plenty of tools" is a way too generic, don't you think?

Comment: Not as generic as your answer. The solution to _"my query is slow"_ is not _"rebuild your indexes"_, but _"find out why"_. I've named a few steps in my comments on the question.